# Why massToMove is undefined

Tags: javascript

Hello I want to return massToMove from my algorithm. But I get undefined, when I console.log() inside the loop I got the proper number. Why it is undefined and how can I prevent that? It is quiet weird because variable is defined '0' and changed inside the loop.

```
let numberOfElephants = 6;
let massOfElephants = [2400, 2000, 1200, 2400, 1600, 4000];
let startOrder = [1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2];
let endOrder = [5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 1];

const sortElephants = (
  numberOfElephants,
  massOfElephants,
  elephantsOrder,
  proposedOrder
) => {
  const elephantObject = [];
  elephantsOrder.forEach((order, i) => {
    elephantObject.push({ [order]: massOfElephants[i] });
  });
  let massToMove = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfElephants; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numberOfElephants; j++) {
      if (startOrder[i] === proposedOrder[j]) {
        if (
          startOrder.indexOf(startOrder[i]) ===
          endOrder.indexOf(proposedOrder[j])
        )
          return;
        const indexOfCorrect = proposedOrder.findIndex(
          (num) => num === endOrder[j]
        );
        const itemAtGivenOrder = startOrder[indexOfCorrect];

        let isCorrect =
          endOrder.indexOf(itemAtGivenOrder) ===
          startOrder.indexOf(itemAtGivenOrder);

        let temp;
        temp = startOrder[indexOfCorrect];

        startOrder[indexOfCorrect] = startOrder[i];

        startOrder[i] = temp;

        const elephantAtGivenCorrectIndex = elephantObject.find(
          (elephant) => elephant[itemAtGivenOrder.toString()]
        );

        const startingElephant = elephantObject.find(
          (elephant) => elephant[startOrder[i]]
        );

        if (!isCorrect) {
          massToMove += startingElephant[startOrder[i]];
        } else {
          massToMove +=
            elephantAtGivenCorrectIndex[itemAtGivenOrder] +
            startingElephant[startOrder[i]];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return massToMove;
};
```

console.log(sortElephants(numberOfElephants, massOfElephants, startOrder, endOrder));

Comment: Are you sure the things you're adding to it are defined?

Comment: at the  place you adding values to `massToMove` might be undefined that's why,

Comment: What parameters are you calling `sortElephants()` with?

Comment: @Azad If you add `undefined` you'll get `NaN`, not `undefined`.

Comment: Please show how you're printing the result. Post a [mre].

Comment: This is returning at `if (
          startOrder.indexOf(startOrder[i]) ===
          endOrder.indexOf(proposedOrder[j])
        )
          return;`, so there's no return value.

Comment: What is the goal of this algorithm? You've got 3 nested loops, which is almost never necessary

Comment: This algorithm needs to sort the startOrder array to be the same like endOrder array. Every value of the start order has weight. 1 weight 2400, 4 has 2000, and 5 has 1200. My goal is to sort them with the lowest weight possible. If you move 1 and 4 it is sum of 4400 weight which has to be added to massToMove. The correct output is 11200 @mstephen19

Comment: @Kay I'm getting 14400

Comment: It means one pair is moved in bad order, I struggle with that

Comment: My point was to create the minimum value, then check if the minimum value is correct or not. If it is correct do not move if it is incorrect then swap this variable and leave the most "weighted variables" to the end. So I was thinking about sorting from the least weighted to the most weighted.